# Inertia question textbook question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string, moment-of-inertia

A pendulum comprised of a 5 kg ball of radius 0.1m on the end of a string with length 2m swings back and forth. What is the moment of inertia of the system. Assume the string is massless.

How can I solve this problem? I tried googling it but all I can find is how to find the velocity/oscillations.

Comment: Try googling again. Like [in this post](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-osuniversityphysics/chapter/10-5-calculating-moments-of-inertia/) which as the exact same problem somewhere in the middle of the post.

Comment: Hint: What is the definition of moment of inertia? Also, moment of inertia depends on a choosing specific point in space as a reference.

Comment: This is a direct homework question no effort shown

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use moment of inertia for a sphere rotating about COM, $I=\dfrac{2}{5}mR^2$ and parallel axis theorem, $I_P = I_{\rm COM} + md^2$.

Answer (score 0):

"How can I solve this problem?"

1. Use a reference to find the mass moment of inertia of a sphere at its center.
2. Use the parallel axis theorem to translate the MMOI from the center to the pivot.